# Spring boot Exception custom handling - Unexpected HTTP status

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception

I am trying to implement some custom exception handlers in my spring boot application which will be able to handle custom exceptions and display appropiate message and status code.

My issue : Getting http status = 500 even though the response body is according to my custom handler.

Code :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler({ BadRequestValidationFailureException.class, Exception.class })
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAll(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {

    ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getMessage());

    return new ResponseEntity<Object>( apiError, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST );

}
```

And throwing exception as :

```
throw new BadRequestValidationFailureException( "ERROR_CODE", "THIS IS THE MESSAGE" );
```

The output is :

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-09-20T17:44:01.502Z",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "com.hotstar.payment.exception.BadRequestValidationFailureException",
"message": "[ ERROR_CODE ] THIS IS THE MESSAGE",
"path": "/my/api/path"
}
```

The weird thing is that the http response status is 500.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. Had to set another annotation :

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, code = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason = "some reason")
```

Add this to `handleAll` method.

Answer (score 0):

I've made good experiences with the following pattern:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    private static final Map<MyProjectErrorCode, HttpStatus> CODE_STATUS_MAP = new EnumMap<>(MyProjectErrorCode.class);

    static {
        CODE_STATUS_MAP.put(MyProjectErrorCode.MYPROJ_ILLEGAL_PROPERTY, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        CODE_STATUS_MAP.put(MyProjectErrorCode.MYPROJ_FOO, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        CODE_STATUS_MAP.put(MyProjectErrorCode.MYPROJ_THIRDPARTYX_CLIENT, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        CODE_STATUS_MAP.put(MyProjectErrorCode.MYPROJ_UNKNOWN, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        CODE_STATUS_MAP.put(MyProjectErrorCode.THIRDPARTYX_BAR, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        CODE_STATUS_MAP.put(MyProjectErrorCode.THIRDPARTYX_UNKNOWN, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MyProjectException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleMyProjectException(MyProjectException ex) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = createErrorResponse(ex.getErrorCode(), ex.getMessage());
        HttpStatus httpStatus = determineHttpStatus(ex.getErrorCode());
        return handleErrorResponse(errorResponse, httpStatus);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleIllegalArgumentException(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        MyProjectErrorCode errorCode = MyProjectErrorCode.MYPROJ_ILLEGAL_PROPERTY;
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = createErrorResponse(errorCode, ex.getMessage());
        HttpStatus httpStatus = determineHttpStatus(errorCode);
        return handleErrorResponse(errorResponse, httpStatus);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleRuntimeException(RuntimeException ex) {
        MyProjectErrorCode errorCode = MyProjectErrorCode.MYPROJ_UNKNOWN;
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = createErrorResponse(errorCode, ex.getMessage());
        HttpStatus httpStatus = determineHttpStatus(errorCode);
        return handleErrorResponse(errorResponse, httpStatus);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleErrorResponse(ErrorResponse errorResponse, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, httpStatus);
    }

    private ErrorResponse createErrorResponse(MyProjectErrorCode errorCode, String message) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();
        errorResponse.setErrorCode(errorCode.name());
        errorResponse.setErrorMessage(message);
        return errorResponse;
    }

    private HttpStatus determineHttpStatus(MyProjectErrorCode errorCode) {
        return CODE_STATUS_MAP.getOrDefault(errorCode, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

The client can get the HttpStatus from the Http response - no need to add it to the JSON body.

The project specific MyProjectErrorCode enum allows you to communicate to the clients a detailed error code. The client can analyze this error code and take the appropriate action or display a localized (specific or generic) error message based on the error code.

MyProjectErrorCode also allows you to communicate if the error was created in your code (starting with MYPROJ_) or if the error is forwarded from the third party 'x' service (starting with THIRDPARTYX_).

You can also create subclasses of MyProjectException and ErrorResponse to transport more specific data for specific cases - just add an additional expcetion handler method for that exception.